# dancer2 with json serializer but die returns html

Tags: json, perl, dancer, die

I am migrating a Dancer app to Dancer2.  I have a ton of typical die() messages which are coming out html formatted instead of JSON formatted.

in my module:

```
## We want pretty JSON.
set engines => {
    serializer => {
        JSON => {
            convert_blessed => 1,
            pretty          => 1,
        }
    }
};
set serializer => 'JSON';
set charset => 'utf8';
```

And later in a route, when the data is invalid we die.

```
get qr{/hardware/?$}i => sub {
  my $params = params;

  if (exists($params->{id})) {  
    if ($params->{id} =~ /^\d+$/) {
      forward "/hardware/${\$params->{id}}", {}; 
    }
    else {
      die "You must supply a numeric Hardware ID.";
    }
  }
  return($api->handle_request('API::Hardware', 'list', $params));
};
```

However, the die response is not in JSON, it is HTML. Any clues as to how I can force die() responses into json, for consistency in my restful api?

Comment: I assume the HTML you're getting back is a 500 Internal Server Error page from your webserver, no? I wouldn't `die` just because somebody used your API incorrectly by forgetting a required parameter; instead, I would return a user-friendly error message in a format consistent with every other API request.

Comment: Actually, I want the error in JSON, not HTML because the callers/users of the API are expecting JSON.

Comment: That's exactly what I said you should do: "return a user-friendly error message in a format consistent with every other API request." That's not what `die` does; `die` throws an exception, and if you don't catch it with `eval` or `$SIG{__DIE__}`, your program will halt immediately and write an error to STDERR. So don't `die`; instead, `return` a JSON response containing the error.